# indexing table rows js/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been tryin to index my table rows but unsuccessfully. The best I could do was come up with the code the could maybe reindex every row in the table everytime i add new table row, but it doesnt work. I think something is wrong with syntax, but I'm not sure what. JS part:

```
$("#pridet").click(function(){
  $("table tbody tr").first().clone().prependTo("table tbody");
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  document.getElementsByName("tabelis").innerHTML = x.rowIndex;
});
```

I realise something is fatally wrong with the second part (like directing where to write what index maybe?)

code on html file:

```
<button id = "pridet">pridet</button>
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-inverse">
    <thead id = "headings" class = "thead-default">
      <tr>
        <th>Tabelio Nr.</th>
        <th>Vardas</th>
        <th>Pavardė</th>
        <th>Pareigos</th>
        <th>Bazinė alga, €</th>
        <th>Valandinis atlyginimas, €</th>
        <th>Veiksmai</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class = "thead-default">
      <tr>
        <td>Vidurkis</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10000</td>
        <td>17.3</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class = "tabelis">1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        <td>
          <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
          <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class = "tabelis">2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>blum</td>
        <td>
          <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p> -->
          <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p> -->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class = "tabelis">3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>blum</td>
        <td>
          <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p> -->
          <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p> -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <script src="script.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script>
    function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
  };
  </script>
```

I could probably count the total number of rows with something like this

```
$("#counter").text( $("table tbody tr").length );
```

and use the value to insert numbers into table cells somehow

EDIT: didnt mention this before, but table rows have to eb added at the top of the table (below thead)

Comment: Try to add the row at the bottom of the table. Count the number of rows in table and add 1 with the count and push it in the last row's first td.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have the row index in the first column of body row you can select each one with:

```
$('#myTable tbody tr td:nth-child(1)')
```

and you can cycle using [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to iterate on every index in order to update it.

```js
function updateRowIndex() {
    $('#myTable tbody tr td:nth-child(1)').each(function(idx, ele) {
        ele.textContent = idx + 1;
    });
}

function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
    updateRowIndex();
};

$("#pridet").on('click', function(e) {
    $("table tbody tr").first().clone().prependTo("table tbody");
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    document.getElementsByName("tabelis").innerHTML = x.rowIndex;
    updateRowIndex();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button id = "pridet">pridet</button>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-inverse">
    <thead id = "headings" class = "thead-default">
    <tr>
        <th>Tabelio Nr.</th>
        <th>Vardas</th>
        <th>Pavardė</th>
        <th>Pareigos</th>
        <th>Bazinė alga, €</th>
        <th>Valandinis atlyginimas, €</th>
        <th>Veiksmai</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class = "thead-default">
    <tr>
        <td>Vidurkis</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10000</td>
        <td>17.3</td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class = "tabelis">1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        <td>
            <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
            <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "tabelis">2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>blum</td>
        <td>
            <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p> -->
            <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p> -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class = "tabelis">3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>blum</td>
        <td>
            <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p> -->
            <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p> -->
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this works great, except with when im trying to delete rows. ive encountered a problem. that is, deleteRow function doesnt execute if its on separate js file, only when on main html in script section. any idea why?

Comment: @NulisDefo you need to include the separate js file like for jQuery. Of couse, before using the function.

Comment: the culprit was that i put code in '$(document).ready(function(){})' as per w3schools examples if anyone encounters something like that. with this fixed, ur suggestion works flawless. need to look into each() more

Comment: @NulisDefo I'm glad for you. Right, it's a good idea to go in depth with .each() .

Answer (score 2):

```js
$("#pridet").click(function(){
  var new_row = $("table tbody tr").first().clone();
  $('table tbody').append(new_row);
  $('table tr:last').find('td:first').html($('table tbody tr').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id = "pridet">pridet</button>
  <table id="myTable" class="table table-inverse" border='1'>
    <thead id = "headings" class = "thead-default">
      <tr>
        <th>Tabelio Nr.</th>
        <th>Vardas</th>
        <th>Pavardė</th>
        <th>Pareigos</th>
        <th>Bazinė alga, €</th>
        <th>Valandinis atlyginimas, €</th>
        <th>Veiksmai</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot class = "thead-default">
      <tr>
        <td>Vidurkis</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>10000</td>
        <td>17.3</td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class = "tabelis">1</td>
        <td>Mark</td>
        <td>Otto</td>
        <td>@mdo</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td>
        <td>
          <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p>
          <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0" onclick="deleteRow(this)"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class = "tabelis">2</td>
        <td>Jacob</td>
        <td>Thornton</td>
        <td>@fat</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>blum</td>
        <td>
          <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p> -->
          <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p> -->
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class = "tabelis">3</td>
        <td>Larry</td>
        <td>the Bird</td>
        <td>@twitter</td>
        <td>bla</td>
        <td>blum</td>
        <td>
          <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-edit"></span></p> -->
          <!-- <p class = "btn" style = "width:10%; padding-bottom:0; margin-bottom:0; border-bottom:0"><span class = "fa fa-trash"></span></p> -->
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I've achieved similiar result. now im trying to acheive that it would index every table row

Comment: @NulisDefo please accept the answer if it helped you and for helping others to find it easily.